# Repeatedly getting "Date cannot be resosolved to a type" errors for this line of java code

Tags: java, eclipse

First of all, I'm not a programmer, but a layman working with codes insofar as they relate to banking, invoicing, and similar tasks (I work as an accountant).

I am trying to set up a code in Java meant to calculate a unique number sequence legally required to be printed on invoices, according to instructions on state websites. I am working on the project through Eclipse. This is the line which always has two errors no matter what I try:

`String datVrij = new SimpleDateFormat( "22.09.2021 12:48:34" ).format( new Date() );`

The errors read:

1. Date cannot be resolved to a type
2. SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type

Have I written something wrong? The things imported so far are only these:

`import java.io.FileInputStream;`

`import java.security.Key;`

`import java.security.KeyStore;`

`import java.security.PrivateKey;`

`import java.security.Signature;`

`import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;`

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I will gladly provide more information if that's what's needed.

Comment: you have not imported `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` into your class

Comment: If you are using at least Java version 8, it is recommended to use class [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) rather than `SimpleDateFormat` and class [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) rather than class `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments stated, you probably didnt import
`java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`